# _wrapped() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request': Issue with method decorator. (Django, Ratelimit Library)

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to use a method decorator so I can apply a decorator to the get_queryset method. My main goal is to limit the number of GET requests per minute to avoid query spam. Although, the problem is the decorator keeps throwing an error as written in the title. I've tried switching the order of and adding the self and request parameters, but so far no luck. Thanks!

Ratelimit Library: https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html
(Ctrl-F to class-based views section.)

```
class ConnectMe(ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'users/connect_me.html'
    context_object_name = 'profiles'
    paginate_by = 10

    @method_decorator(ratelimit(key='ip', rate='1/m', method='GET'))
    def get_queryset(self):
        # original qs
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems here:

1. a mixin should be listed before the view, so `ConnectMe(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView)`;
2. the method decorator should decorate the dispatch method; and
3. the [**`.get_queryset()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) does not take a `request` parameter.

You thus implement this like:

```
@method_decorator(ratelimit(key='ip', rate='1/m', method='GET'), name='dispatch')
class ConnectMe(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'users/connect_me.html'
    context_object_name = 'profiles'
    paginate_by = 10
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        # original qs
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        # …
        return qs
```

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `ConnectMeView`, instead of <s>`ConnectMe`</s>.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response and the extra advice, it helps a lot! Works great with no errors!